# How to simplify JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, simplify

I want to simplify the following code:
(As you can see I have a lot of `document.getElementById`)

```
clickText() {
  document.getElementById("choiceInput").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dateInput").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("textInput").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('buttonFont').classList.remove('buttonUnselectAfterClick');
  document.getElementById('buttonFont').classList.add('buttonSelectAfterClick');
  document.getElementById('buttonCalendar').classList.remove('buttonSelectAfterClick');
  document.getElementById('buttonCalendar').classList.add('buttonUnselectAfterClick');
  document.getElementById('buttonBoolean').classList.remove('buttonSelectAfterClick');
  document.getElementById('buttonBoolean').classList.add('buttonUnselectAfterClick');
}
```

Also, I'm using reactjs.

Comment: Use class instead

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I can't, I need to have distinct elements

Comment: Maybe use jQuery?

Comment: Create a helper function and call it like `addClassToElement('buttonFont', 'buttonUnselectAfterClick')`.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Yes I use react but I'm a begineer, I don't know how to do what you mean

Comment: @AlessioCammarata look on that example https://codepen.io/_danko/pen/EypdyW

Comment: @ivooQ He is already using react.. why add jQuery to it?

Comment: @Alessio you need to learn a bit more about [react](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) as what you are asking can be solved an elegant "react" way

Comment: if you use React you shouldn't manipulate DOM directly, React is not for that. even if you have to do, you should use React Ref for access DOM https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Map, Set and for...of loop to simplify the code a little bit by grouping them, and no library and framework is needed:

```
const displayList = new Map([['choiceInput', 'none'], ['dateInput', 'none'], ['textInput', 'block']]);
const eventList = new Set(['buttonFont', 'buttonCalendar', 'buttonBoolean']);

clickText() {
  // For display attr
  for([key, val] of displayList) {
     document.getElementById(key).style.display = val;
  }

  // For events
  for(item of eventList) {
   document.getElementById(item).classList.remove('buttonUnselectAfterClick');
document.getElementById(item).classList.add('buttonUnselectAfterClick');
  }
}
```

Comment: You should wrap into  methods for a cleaner solution. But it's a good option

Comment: @segu Thanks! I have wrapped it into the same function.

Comment: Good solution, but you should extract creating Map and Set out form the click. You don't need to create this list every time button clicked